# Does there exist $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $\inf\{a_N , a_{N+1}, \cdots\}= \liminf a_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

> If $\liminf a_n=m\in \mathbb R$, does there exists $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $\inf\{a_N, a_{N+1},\cdots\}= m$?

This is an intriguing question I encounter when I am learning the limit superiors and limit inferiors.

I think we can find such an $N$. But I'm struggling in proving it.

I guess it has something to do with the limit inferior being an increasing sequence.

Can anyone share their opinions/insights on this, and share some techniques dealing with limit superiors/inferiors?

Comment: You appear to be using $N$ to stand for a couple of different things, no?  Also, it';s hard to guess which of your numbers are meant to be subscripts.  Is aN+1  meant to be $a_{N+1}$ for example?

Comment: It would be easier to understand if you would repeat the headline-question inside of the question, with all the possibilities of better readability, such as distinguishing mathbord font N from simple N.

Comment: Hint: If $a_n$ is increasing the $\mbox{inf} \{a_N, a_{N+1},...\}=a_{N}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take : $a_n=\frac{-1}{n}$, the limit inferior of this sequence is 0, but there is no $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $0=inf\{a_N,a_{N+1}.....\}$ .

Answer (score 0):

No it is not true. Just consider the sequence $-1/n$.